# Class not found - When i use a namspace

Tags: php, database, pdo

I learn to use namespaces and I come across an error when I want to use these names which is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mehdi\Blog\Model\PDO' not found in C:\Users\Mehdi\Desktop\PROJETS Perso\PHP - EXO\Blog- Commentaires PHP\model\Manager.php on line 9
```

I use it for my model and controller :

1. controller

   - frontend.php -> He need my PostManager Class and CommentManager Class, here is the code :

   ```
   use Mehdi\Blog\Model\PostManager;
   use Mehdi\Blog\Model\CommentManager;
   require_once('model/PostManager.php');
   require_once('model/CommentManager.php');
   ```
2. model

   - CommentManager.php -> Need Database, here is the code :

   ```
   namespace Mehdi\Blog\Model;
   use Mehdi\Blog\Model\Manager;
   require_once('Manager.php');
   ```

   - Manager.php -> Have my DataBase, here is the code :

   ```
   namespace Mehdi\Blog\Model;
   ```

   - PostManager.php -> Need Database, here is the code :

   ```
   namespace Mehdi\Blog\Model;
   use Mehdi\Blog\Model\Manager;
   require_once('Manager.php');
   ```

My database PDO code :

```
<?php

namespace Mehdi\Blog\Model;

class Manager
{
    protected function dbConnect()
    {
        $bdd = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lhairdut_newsletter;charset=utf8', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));    
        return $bdd; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor -- use an autoloader and get rid of all the `require_once` statements. Your naming already fits PSR-4, there's no need to manually manage this stuff.

Comment: (Oops, **almost** fits PSR-4... you'd need to use `Model` instead of `model` for the subdir name.)

Comment: You are missing the autoloader class, normally installed thru composer and added to the index of your application. Here https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/how-to-autoload-with-composer

Comment: Ok but I do not understand what it says on your link, I do not know json or the command line. There would not be another simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All looks very messy.

- Try to follow folder structure,
- And put backslash, I hope that's the name for `\`, before every single PDO class, because you are in a namespace something\blog\something. System will think that this class also belong to this namespace and it does not. With backslash you say it belong to root namespace where it truly belong.

Code:

```
$bdd = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lhairdut_newsletter;charset=utf8', 'root', '', array(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```